# Web service calls return HTTP 500 Internal Server Error on my SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint site that was running without any problem. Few days ago the search stopped working with an error in the crawl log

> The crawler could not communicate with the server. Check that the
>   server is available and that the firewall access is configured
>   correctly

From the ULS log I was able to see that the crawler is trying to call a web service **_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx**, but it is failing with error **HTTP 500 Internal Server Error**. I believe because of this failure the crawl is not working in the farm. 
When I tried to call other built-in webservices in SP2013 (such as lists.asmx?WSDL), I noticed that all the ASMX services have the same problem.

Can anybody please help me to figure out what is going wrong in SharePoint? I tried to see the ULS and event viewer; nothing logged there.

Is there any way I can "reinstall" the ASMX web services in SharePoint?

## UPDATE:

The web services are not working on the site collection root site. For any subsite the web services works properly. I am still confused.

Thank you

Comment: You probably could get more info from logs: either from the Windows Event Viewer (eventvwr.exe, "Application" section) or from the SharePoint ULS logs. "500" means 'internal server error', so you should get something from the logs.

Comment: Check if all SharePoint related app pools are still running as expected under the IIS management panel.

Comment: Surprising to me, there is nothing I can see in ULS or Event Viewer. The ULS got just this entry "Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://server:80/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx)). Execution Time=8.09907404432686 0d3f6d9d-1299-b02e-5367-a9b7a8b4e056"

Comment: @SPArchaeologist the App pools are running

Comment: Do you actually have a root site collection (i.e. can you browse `http://SharePointServer/`)?

Comment: Yes, I do have a site collection. I created a new web application but the issue is same there. I believe previous site admin might have played around with some configurations (config file or something).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. It was a mistake in the **web.config** located at **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI**.
After fixing the issue the web services started working for the site collection root site.

Comment: But how did the web.config mistake occur? Is it human mistake?

Comment: Yes, a developer created a custom utility to update the web configs by using   "SPWebConfigModification" but ended up some duplicate values there (developer error of course).

Answer (score -1):

I added this in the web.config in the ISAPI folder(**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI**) and my search crawl stopped crawling.

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <authorization>
        <Allow users= "*" />
           <Deny users= "?" />
     </authorization>
  </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

I added this to stop anonymous access to my external facing site. Now I removed this from web.config and search is working fine.